# How to run Dart Editor without firewall privileges?

Tags: usb, dart, admin, firewall, portability

Okay, I'm developing a web app using Dart, I'm making encrypter - which works fine at home. But, I'm in college and I need to run my Dart app from a USB stick. When I run my Dart app, the version of Chrome that comes with Dart opens but nothing loads. I have the **"stop loading this page"** button showing, which tells me that it is trying to load something, but I've left it for half an hour and nothing happens. I think it's because I cannot give Dart any Firewall privileges, because I'm not an admin, the VM that Dart uses won't launch. Has anybody got any tips of how to get around this?

Comment: Do you write a console app or a web page? Do you launch the application from the Darteditor? How to you launch it? Context menu on the file > run?

Comment: Hi Zoechi, I'm creating a web page and I use the "Run" button on the menu bar

Comment: You could try starting chrome with the –allow-file-access-from-files flag, and then just opening the html file from the file system, rather than over http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disconnected my notebook from the network and Darteditor runs just fine. I can start web pages without any problem.

Probably Darteditor tries to download pub dependencies which won't work without a network connection.

If you can open a public website like google.com in your browser then it's probably not a firewall limitation. AFAIK Dart uses only HTTP port 80 which is usually open. 
If your HTTP connection goes over a proxy that might not work - that is a common problem with Dart.

Comment: When you run an app in Dartium from the editor, a webserver is started  on localhost. OP is probably right that this webserver is blocked by his firewall. Pub only runs if you run pub get/upgrade.